# Convert table to html and group in to divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

update: almost done! problem is that the productrow im trying to grouop gets divided into two groups: https://jsfiddle.net/g3zrh5y5/1/

I have a HTML table that I would like to convert and group to divs. I have dont his succesfully with tableanarchy.js (http://codepen.io/KurtWM/pen/AJpEw) on another table on my site, but on this table the setup is a bit different and I cant make it to work.

I need to remove the divider table row, and group the rest in divs as the example shows. Any idea how I do this?

```
 <tbody>
  <tr>
    <td class="unfoldedlabel" colspan="6"><a href="javascript://" name=
    "_ec_pd6_cc/cL" id="_ec_pd6_cc/cL" onclick=
    "if( UI.pb_boolean(this, 'click') ) {} return false;">Backup/datalagring/Raid
    Controllers</a></td>
  </tr>

   //group this ---->
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><a href=
    "">
    <img src="/imgs" alt="" /></a></td>

    <td colspan="3"><a href=
    "">
    HP Flash Backed Write Cache - RAID controller cache memory (1GB)</a></td>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>534562-B21</td>

    <td>HP</td>

    <td>0</td>

    <td>4&nbsp;127,97SEK</td>

    <td><input type="button" id="rpb13804" class="actionbutton" value="K&Ouml;P NU"
    onclick="buy(this, 13804, null, null,null, '/ajax/buy')" /></td>
  </tr>
 //end group ---->

 //remove this ---->
  <tr>
    <td class="divider" colspan="6"></td>
  </tr>
  //end remove ---->

 //group this ---->
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="2"><a href=
    "">
    <img src="/imgs/9248a5f8-1a45-40c1-b254-52ab24881150/40/40" alt="" /></a></td>

    <td colspan="3"><a href=
    "">
    HP Flash Backed Write Cache - RAID controller cache memory (512MB) - for ProLiant
    BL460c G7, BL620C G7, BL680c G7, DL165 G7, DL360 G7, DL370 G6, DL980 G7, ML110
    G7</a></td>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>

    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>534916-B21</td>

    <td>HP</td>

    <td>0</td>

    <td>3&nbsp;260,99SEK</td>

    <td><input type="button" id="rpb28314" class="actionbutton" value="K&Ouml;P NU"
    onclick="buy(this, 28314, null, null,null, '/ajax/buy')" /></td>
  </tr>
//end group ---->

</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate the table rows and exclude the rows you don't need. Here is a working fiddle

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.group-btn').click(function(){
    // Lets create the main div
    var div = $('<div />', {id: '#myDiv', class: 'new-div'});
  
    // Let's start iterating the body rows
    $('.myTable tbody tr').each(function(index, row) {
      // Exclude divider rows
      if(!$(row).hasClass('divider')) {
        // Let's iterate the columns of the row
        $(row).find('td').each(function(index, column){
          // This is a simple example that extract the column text that's why i create a simple <p> tag
          
          // Let's exclude tds that have "exclude" class
          if(!$(column).hasClass('exclude')) {
              var paragraph = $(column).html();
          
              $(div).append(paragraph).append('<br/>');
          }
        });
      }
    });
        
    // And finally we append the div to the "append-here" div
    $('.append-here').append(div)
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid black
}

table tr td{
  border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="group-btn">Click me!</button>

<table class="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>col 1-1</th>
      <th>col 2-1</th>
      <th>col 3-1</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 1-2</td>
      <td class="exclude">Val 2-2</td>
      <td>Val 3-2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 1-3</td>
      <td>Val 2-3</td>
      <td class="exclude">Val 3-3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="divider">
      <td colspan="3">DIVIDER</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Val 1-5</td>
      <td>Val 2-5</td>
      <td>Val 3-5</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>


<div class="append-here">
  <p>Here is where you append the divs</p>
</div>
```

I've made a little change: the "divider" class is in the `tr` and not in the `td`

*** UPDATE ***

I've added this line of code

```
if(!$(column).hasClass('exclude')) {
    var paragraph = $(column).html();
    $(div).append(paragraph).append('<br/>');
}
```

That permits you to check whatever class you need to check in order to include/exclude `td`s elements

Comment: @IIGala Hmm thanks! It *almost* works - it divides the group into two halfs. I also realized I have a td class I need to exclude from this: unfoldedlabel. Updated my fiddle with a close example of the problem!

Comment: Thanks @Xeptor if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Hmm yeah it removed the row with the class. I dont think i was especially clear - I dont want to remove it, i just wanted it to be excluded from the script, which I realized wont work, so i need all rows with that class to have its own, same class, since its a repeating element and that works as an divided/header. the big problem though is that my product I wanted to group is divided into two groups, as this fiddle example shows: https://jsfiddle.net/g3zrh5y5/1/. any idea why?

Comment: The question was to group the elements inside one div - if you look at this fiddle: you can see that for an example  div1 and div2 are seperate- they should be in the same container. So its very close!

Comment: @IIGala Oh couldn't link the fiddle - its on top of my original post with the example :)

Comment: Ok ok, I looked at it very fast... Sorry, i modify my answer in order to include everything in one div

Comment: I think Im not too clear, my mistake sorry. now everything is inside one parent container - my goal was closer to the fiddle i have with your original code. If you look at the fiddle, you can see two products  with @IIGala image, text and button. I want these two inside their own container. with your code each product is divided in two seperate groups - product one has div 2 and 3, and product two has div 4 and 5. div 1 and 2 should be one div, and div 4 and 5 the same. your original code almost does this!